# Why some kernel config didn't show in .config

Tags: linux, kernel, yocto

I search .config, there is no

```
CONFIG_ACPI_NUMA
```

but I can see it when doing menuconfig.

Another question, I can see this in .config

```
# CONFIG_NUMA is not set
```

Why CONFIG_ACPI_NUMA didn't show in .config as

```
# CONFIG_ACPI_NUMA is not set  ( There is no this line in .config )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a kernel expert, but all the possibles configs are not listed in the `.config` file.

It seems that a configuration appear when its dependencies are met. [Maybe a dependency is not met](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/ACPI_NUMA.html):

```
depends on: ( CONFIG_NUMA ) && (( CONFIG_X86 || CONFIG_IA64 || CONFIG_ARM64 )) && ( CONFIG_IA64 || CONFIG_ARM64 )
```